# How to pass arguments in I18n.translate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I18n.translate can translate error.messages like this:

```
I18n.translate('error.messages.taken')
-> has already been taken
```

But there are some error messages that contains arguments like:

```
I18n.translate('error.messages.greater_than_or_equal_to')
-> must be greater than or equal to %{count}"
```

Is it possible to pass the argument ‘count’ in the I18n.translate?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can pass the params after the key

```
I18n.translate('error.messages.greater_than_or_equal_to', count: 2)
```

Answer (score 6):

For multiple params it could be:

```
I18n.translate('error.messages.greater_than_or_equal_to', {
  count: 2,
  foo: 'bar'
})
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to pass a hash(dynamic) argument, you can use the double splat operator `**`.

```rb
values = { count: 2, name: 'John' }
I18n.t('error.messages.greater_than_or_equal_to', **values)
```

Answer (score 2):

This would allow you to add as many arguments as you want

```
I18n.translate('error.messages.greater_than_or_equal_to {arg1}').replace('{arg1}', count)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
"greeting": "hi {name}"
```

You need to write

```
i18n.translate('greeting', {values: {name: 'John'}});
```

Answer (score 0):

In ROR I was able to pass multiple arguments using

`#app/mailers/sample_mailer.rb`

`(to: email, subject: t('<mailer_scope>.<action_name>.subject', <locale_variable_name_1>: <Rails_variable_name_1>, <locale_variable_name_2>: <Rails_variable_name_2>))`

`#config/locales/en.yml`

```
mailer_scope:
    action_name:
      `subject: "Insert e-mail subject here: %{locale_variable_name_1} - %{locale_variable_name_2}"
```

You may read this official [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-action-mailer-e-mail-subjects) from Rails guides.